# why in c language EOF IS -1?

Tags: c

in c language i am using EOF .....why EOF IS -1 ? why not other value?

Comment: Mark Byers's answer is correct. For this to work, you must always store the output of `getchar` or the like as `int`, not `char`; `(int) -1` is not a valid character, but `(char) -1` is.

Answer (score 10):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file):

> The actual value of EOF is system-dependent (but is commonly -1, such as in [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/EOF-and-Errors.html)) and is unequal to any valid character code.

It can't be any value in 0 - 255 because these are valid values for characters on most systems. For example if EOF were 0 then you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between reading a 0 and reaching the end of file.

-1 is the obvious remaining choice.

You may also want to consider using `feof` instead:

> Since EOF is used to report both end of file and random errors, it's often better to use the feof function to check explicitly for end of file and ferror to check for errors.

Comment: +1 The range 0--255 applies if `CHAR_BIT` is 8; but, no matter what `CHAR_BIT`'s value is, -1 is never a valid value.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young - 0 - 255 is also the range that `unsigned char` is guaranteed to be able to hold by the standard. `CHAR_BIT` can be greater than 8, but it has to be at least 8.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Right; I was thinking of the case where `CHAR_BIT` is 16 or 32, not 7 or anything like that. :-)

Comment: The ISO C standard says that the value is negative. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) was incomplete ("unequal to any valid character code" was also incorrect or ambiguous with signed `char`), and I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't. It is defined to be an implementation-defined negative int constant. It must be negative so that one can distinguish it easily from an *unsigned char*. in most implementations it is indeed -1, but that is not required by the C standard.

The historic reason for choosing -1 was that the character classification functions (see <ctype.h>) can be implemented as simple array lookups. And it is the "nearest" value that doesn't fit into an unsigned char.

**[Update:]** Making the character classification functions efficient was probably not the main reason for choosing -1 in the first place. I don't know all the historical details, but it is the most obvious decision. It had to be negative since there are machines whose `char` type didn't have exactly 8 bits, so choosing a positive value would be difficult. It had to be large enough so that it is not a valid value for `unsigned char`, yet small enough to fit into an int. And when you have to choose a negative number, why should you take an arbitrary large negative number? That leaves -1 as the best choice.

Comment: Not convinced about the array lookup argument, but +1 for not having to be -1.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getchar#EOF_pitfall and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Answer (score 0):

```
int c;

c = getchar();
while(!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
  ...
  c = getchar();
}
```

You should be careful to consider the effect of end of file or error on any tests you make on these values. Consider this loop, intended to scan all characters up to the next whitespace character received:

```
int c;

c = getchar();
while(!isspace(c)) {
  ...
  c = getchar();
}
```

If EOF is returned before any whitespace is detected then this loop may never terminate (since it is not a whitespace character). A better way to write this would be:

```
int c;

c = getchar();
while(!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin) && !isspace(c)) {
  ...
  c = getchar();
}
```

Finally, it is worth noting that although EOF is usually -1, all the standard promises is that it is a negative integral constant with type int.

Comment: I've written C on a DSP system where sizeof(char)==sizeof(int)==16 bits.  I believe the standard would mandate that default `char` type must be unsigned on any system where sizeof(int)==1, and must be unsigned on any system where the source character set would have values that wouldn't fit in a `signed char`.  Because the compiler was for an embedded system, there was no built-in `getchar()`; I would think if one wanted to add file I/O, the thing to do would be to have it regard files as streams of 8-bit bytes and have read/write methods store one octet in each `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can change the EOF value.
In C program define the macro for EOF=-1 in default,
So you mention EOF in your program, that default c compiler assign value for -1;

for example;

Just you try and get the result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EOF 22
main()
{
   int a;
   a=EOF;
   printf(" Value of a=%d\n",a);
}
```

Output:

Value of a=22

Reason:

That time EOF value is changed