# Why is EOF defined to be −1 when −1 cannot be represented in a char?

Tags: c, char, eof

I'm learning the C programming on a raspberry pi, however I found that my program never catches the EOF successfully. I use `char c=0; printf("%d",c-1);` to test the `char` type, finding that the `char` type ranges from 0 to 255, as an `unsigned short`. but the `EOF` defined in `stdio.h` is (-1). So is the wrong cc package installed on my Pi? how can I fix it? If I changed the `EOF` value in `stdio.h` manually, will there be further problems?

---

what worries me is that ,when I learning from the K&R book, there are examples which use code like `while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)`, I followed that on my Ubuntu machine and it works fine. I just wonder if such kind of syntax is abandoned by modern C practice or there is something conflict in my Raspberry Pi?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
        char c;
        int i=0;
        while ((c=getchar())!=EOF&&i<50) {
                putchar(c);
                i++;
        }
        if (c==EOF)
                printf("\nEOF got.\n");
        while ((c=getchar())!=EOF&&i<500) {
                printf("%d",c);
                i++;
        }
}
```

even when I redirect the input to an file, it keeps printing 255 on the screen, never terminate this program.

---

Finally I found that I'm wrong,In the K&R book, it defined c as an int, not a  char. Problem solved.

Comment: The code `char c=0; printf("%d",c--);` prints `0` because `c` is decremented **after** its value is used in `printf()`. This code doesn't prove anything. Take a look at some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: Post the code that "never catches the EOF successfully" rather than test code.

Comment: to axiac : I changed `c--` to `c-1` in my post.

Comment: you have many wrong assumptions: `char` can represent -1 if it's a signed type (which is the most common configuration). See [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714). And EOF can be any negative values. See [Is EOF always negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624051/995714), [why in c language EOF IS -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4569066/995714)

Answer (score 5):

You need to store the character read by `fgetc()`, `getchar()`, etc. in an `int` so you can catch the `EOF`. This is well-known and has always been the case everywhere. `EOF` must be distinguishable from all proper characters, so it was decided that functions like `fgetc()` return valid characters as non-negative values (even if `char` is signed). An end-of-file condition is signalled by `-1`, which is negative and thus cannot collide with any valid character `fgetc()` could return.

Do not edit the system headers and especially do not change the value of constants defined there. If you do that, you break these headers. Notice that even if you change the value of `EOF` in the headers, this won't change the value functions like `fgetc()` return on end-of-file or error, it just makes `EOF` have the wrong value.

Comment: Furthermore, it's probably for the best to check `feof()` and `ferror()` after any read/write operation that returned unexpected values (like `EOF`).

Comment: @Rhymoid Checking for one of them is sufficient as `feof()` and `ferror()` cannot be raised at the same time as far as I know. Also, the error flag persists until it is cleared with `clearerr()`, an idiom is to continue reading the remainder of the data and then at the end checking the flags as to save a lot of error handling code.

Comment: @chux Your remark is correct, but all actual characters are returned as positive values from `fgetc()` so a distinction can be made. I'm going to edit my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: @chux Better this way?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is EOF defined to be −1 when −1 cannot be represented in a char?

Because `EOF` isn't a character but a state.

Answer (score 2):

> If I changed the EOF value in stdio.h manually, will there be further
>   problems?

Absolutely, since you would be effectively breaking the header entirely. A header is not an actual function, just a set of prototypes and declarations for functions that are defined elsewhere ABSOLUTELY DO NOT change system headers, you will never succeed in doing anything but breaking your code, project and/or worse things.

On the subject of EOF: EOF is not a character, and thus cannot be represented in a character variable. To get around this, most programmers simple use an int value (by default signed) that can interpret the -1 from EOF. The reason that EOF can never be a character is because otherwise there would be one character indistinguishable from the end of file indicator.

Answer (score 1):

`int` versus `char`.

`fgetc()` returns an `int`, not `char`.  The values returned are in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  This is typically 257 different values.  So saving the result in `char, signed char, unsigned char` will lose some distinguishably.

Instead save the `fgetc()` return value in an `int`.  *After* testing for an `EOF` result, the value can be saved as a `char` if needed.

```
// char c;
int c;
...
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF&&i<50) {
  char ch = c;
  ...
```

---

Detail: "Why is `EOF` defined to be −1 when −1 cannot be represented in a `char`?" misleads.  On systems where `char` is signed and `EOF == -1`, a `char` *can* have the value of `EOF`.  Yet on such systems, a `char` can have a value of -1 that represents a character too - they overlap.  So a `char` cannot distinctively represent all `char` and `EOF`.  Best to use an `int` to save the return value of `fgetc()`.

> ... the fgetc function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and ...
>   If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, ... and the fgetc function returns `EOF`. ...  C11 §7.21.7.1 2-3